# Efficient way for nonce generations

Tags: go-ethereum, quorum, nonce

What is the most efficent way/ best practice / better practice for nonce generation that is used for blockchain quorum transactions?

I am currently using etcd mutex global lock for nonce generation that causes bottleneck/ high latency in my application.

My blockchain is a PoA network using IBFT